# LinkedIn throttle limits (messages)

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

We're building a platform using **LinkedIn messages** as part of our user communications. 
Current state of throttle limits *is 10 per user, 5k per application*. 
I am wondering:

1. What are **calls per application**, since LinkedIn requires user tokens
   to send messages and it to does not communicate with server via
   encrypted keys as google drive for example?
2. Any chances to **server-to-server** interaction?
3. Is there a real way to **increase the limitations at least up to a 100
   requests per day or more/limitless** ? Like enterprise plans or smth?

Thanks, appreciate any help!